# how can i obtain earliest day and lastest date per row/item number using Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi

im new to power bi dax. im currently working on getting the earliest date by MO (column MO). Ive tried the dax formula below but it returned the wrong date for one of the MO.

Raw data and expected output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iSxq.png)

Power BI Output with the current dax function:
Column = CALCULATE(MIN('1 (2)'[START DATE ]),FILTER('1 (2)',EARLIER('1 (2)'[MO])))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/351lt.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.